# How can I check if a class property/attribute exist and then set a value for it based on property name matching

Tags: swift, parsing, setattribute

I am parsing a csv file and I want to save the values to a class that I have. The class's attributes should match the ones in the csv after some character parsing and doing a case insensitive compare. Initially I was taking the properties from the csv file then I would do a Mirror reflection of my class object and for loop into that. Then I would do my case insensitive check and parsing in there - if it matches I would set the attribute for the class. As you can see there's extensive use of for loops which isn't good for performance. I have looked for a good solution but still can't find one. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is your exact requirement is it get csv data and map it with your Modal object and if csv have some properties which are present in your modal map those properties ?

Comment: @PravinTate yes I would like to map it straight into my modal object. I have created the modal object to match my csv (mostly) after removing spaces and some characters as well as some differences in capitalisation. But yes that is what I want to do in the most efficient way